# Rolle's theorem and the closed interval

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

I think I was/am missing a key concept of Rolle's theorem.
The question says find the value(s) of c that satisfies Rolle's theorem for
$y=-x^2+2$; $[-2,2]$

I see that this is simply a parabola with vertex at $(0,2)$ and that at that point there is possible a horizontal line (slope$=0$).

The theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ and ***$f(a)=0  $ and $f(b)=0$***, then there is at least one point c in the interval $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

So, I first tested to see if $f(-2)=0$ and it does NOT.  And further $f(2)$ does NOT equal $0$, so I assumed that I could go no further.

Is that correct?  I think maybe what I should do is find the roots of $f(x)$ and if those roots are within $[-2,2]$ [and they ARE], THEN find c.

A little confused on this key concept of Rolle's.  Maybe it was a misprint and they meant to put the interval as $[-\sqrt (2), \sqrt (2)]$ ?

Do the endpoints have to be used in $f(a)$????

Comment: People often use Rolle's theorem to refer to the case where both endpoints take the same value, regardless of whether that value is 0 or not. You can add / subtract a constant function to see that the two formulations are equivalent.

Comment: The question is badly written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a generalization of Rolle theorem which says that if $f(a)=f(b)$ there exists $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Here $f(-2)=f(2)$. This can be easily seen from the previous case, suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$. Define $g$ on $[a,b]$ by $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$, $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and there exists $c$ such that $g'(c)=f'(c)=0$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem